# Using part of a primary key as a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a small MYSQL database, and I currently am having an issue with my entitiy HOME.  Its attributes are ROOM_NUM and BUILD_CODE.  The two make up a composite primary key, with foreign key BUILD_CODE referencing which building it's located in.

I was wondering if it would be possible to have BUILD_CODE be a single char ('a', 'b', 'c', etc...) and then have a primary key for HOME being something like "A302" or "B205".  The first character of that primary key would reference BUILD_CODE, with the remaining numbers being the room number.  Then I'd have a unique single value primary key.  The reason I ask is so that I don't have to have multiple foreign keys in my PERSON table referencing to HOME.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a surrogate key (a sequence) as the primary key of the entity HOME and Use that as the foreign key of the PERSON. And then for BUILD_CODE and ROOM_NUM declare a unique key to maintain the uniqueness of the combination.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like HOME needs its own *separate* identifier. And it doesn't matter what the ID is...as long as it's unique.

Consider the following:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE HOME (ID INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment, ROOM_NUM INTEGER, BUILD_CODE VARCHAR(1), PRIMARY KEY(ID));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE PERSON(ID INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment, NAME VARCHAR(255), HOME_ID INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(ID), FOREIGN KEY(HOME_ID) REFERENCES HOME(ID));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO HOME (ROOM_NUM, BUILD_CODE) VALUES (302, "A"), (205, "B");
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM HOME;
+----+----------+------------+
| ID | ROOM_NUM | BUILD_CODE |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 |      302 | A          |
|  2 |      205 | B          |
+----+----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, HOME_ID) VALUES ("someone", 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM PERSON;
+----+---------+---------+
| ID | NAME    | HOME_ID |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | someone |       1 |
+----+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT PERSON.NAME, HOME.BUILD_CODE, HOME.ROOM_NUM FROM HOME JOIN PERSON ON PERSON.HOME_ID = HOME.ID;
+---------+------------+----------+
| NAME    | BUILD_CODE | ROOM_NUM |
+---------+------------+----------+
| someone | A          |      302 |
+---------+------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You see, it really doesn't matter that `HOME` has `ID` values that don't say much about the rest of its data... *You're only using that field as an instrument to join the two together*.

Of course, you could just as easily have `INSERT`ed a concatenation of the `BUILD_CODE` and `ROOM_NUM` fields into the `ID` field... That would be fine too. But keep in mind that (a) string lookups use more resources than integer lookups, and (b) it's just one more thing that your application needs to maintain (for example: what happens if you start out by calculating the room numbers as A302, but then after seeing larger room numbers, you decide on A00302? You'd have to go through the entire table--and all its associations--and update the `ID`. It's not terribly ideal).

Comment: That would be perfect for what I'm doing.  This database is mainly for testing a piece of software my team is building.  How could I make a concatenated primary key from BUILD_CODE and ROOM_NUM?

Comment: First, you'll have to make sure the `ID` field is a `VARCHAR` instead of an auto-incrementing `INTEGER`. Then you can just do something like: `INSERT INTO HOME (ID, ROOM_NUM, BUILD_CODE) VALUES (CONCAT("A", 302), 302, "A");`

Comment: Is there a way to make it automatically derive the ID from ROOM_NUM and BUILD_CODE, or will I just have to do it manually for every entity entered into the table?

Comment: The short answer: no. The long answer is that there are a few ways you can accomplish something similar, based on what you're really trying to accomplish... (1) You could, again, have a `TRIGGER` add this value based on the other two values. (2) Create a `VIEW`, which is somewhat like a `SELECT` query that behaves like a table. (Your `VIEW` would have the `ID` field, and so you could `JOIN` on that.) (3) Ditch the `ID` field entirely, and give `PERSON` two columns -- one for `ROOM_NUM`, and one for `BUILD_CODE`, and then `JOIN` on *both* those fields.

Comment: My main concern is that the table HOME is redundant.  If its key is just ROOM_NUM and BUILD_CODE, which are FKs in PERSON, I might as well just drop the table entirely and have PERSON relate directly to BUILDING.